# How to sort tree of folders

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a plane tree of folders. This tree has the following properties: id, parent_id, name.

This tree I store in a simple array. The problem is that this array is not sorted.

An element of my array is the simple object like this:

```
var obj = { id: 1, parent_id: null, name: "Folder" }
```

I want to sort it in such a way to be able to see some thing like this:

```
Folder1
  Sub_folder1
    Sub_sub_folder1
  Sub_folder2
    Sub_sub_folder2
```

And so one... I don't want to use recursion and I don't know how to do it properly.

Here is some of my tries. I tryid to add an artificial field which will represented the number of each folder in collection, but it doens't work.

```
var sort = function(list) {

  var f_map = {};
  var sorting_index = 1;
  var tree = angular.copy(list);

  for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {

    var node = tree[i];
    f_map[ node.id ]= { index: i, children: [] };

    if (node.parent_id) {
      f_map[ node.parent_id ].children.push( node.id );
    };

    var idx = 0;
    var visited = {};

    for(var key in f_map) {
      var index = f_map[key].index;
      var node = tree[index];
      if (!visited[node.id]) {
        node.nuid = idx++;
      } else {
        visited[node.id] = true;
      };
      if (f_map[key].children.length) {
        var children = f_map[key].children;
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          var child_id = children[i];
          var child_idx = f_map[child_id].index;
          var child = tree[child_idx];
          child.nuid = idx++;
          visited[child.id] = true;
        };
      };
    };

    tree.sort(function(left, right) {
      return left.nuid - right.nuid;
    });

    return tree;
};
```

Comment: Please add what you tried in a coded example. Would love to help you where you are stuck, but not solve it for you. Also, if you do not know how to do it, then why are you opting out recursion?

Comment: @Ronni Skansing, done. Dont' want to use recursion, because to will make everything slow.

Comment: What does your array look like?  To sort a tree structure you can either sort on the path to the node, use recursion, or use a stack (ie. manually implement recursion).

Comment: @thebjorn added small description of an element of my array. Don't know how to do it properly with stack. Do you have an example?

Comment: Recursion is probably comparatively much faster than you give it credit for - don't assume it won't meet your speed requirements.

Comment: @Dukeling recursion can be changed with stack traversion. I wan't to understant with way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're representing the parent pointer as a reference to the `id` of the parent node, I would first change your representation of the folders into an object representation:

```
var folders = {
    1: {parent_id: null, name: "Folder", path: null},
    ...
};
```

I've added a `path` field, so that I can memoize the results of the following recursive function for finding the full path of a folder:

```
function path(node) {
    if (node.path !== null) return node.path;
    if (node.parent_id === null) {
        node.path = '/' + node.name;
    } else {
        node.path = path(folders[node.parent_id]) + '/' + node.name;
    }
    return node.path;
}
```

Then we can do a Schwartzian transform by first pulling out the field we want to sort on and a reference to the item:

```
var keys = [];

Object.keys(folders).map(function (key) {
    var folder = folders[key];
    keys.push({path: path(folder), id: key});
});
```

then we can sort the keys array:

```
keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    var apath = a.path;
    var bpath = b.path;

    // probably the best way to compare folder paths..
    return apath.localeCompare(bpath);
});
```

and finally we can produce the folders in sorted order by traversing the keys array:

```
var sorted_folders = keys.map(function (item) {
    return folders[item.id];  // .name; or maybe .path; ??
});
```

as is `sorted_folders` will be a list of folder objects, but per the comment, you can easily pull out the needed properties in this step.

Answer (score 1):

First off, recursion is not slow. It is a nice tool to have in your arsenal. It makes solving certain problems much easier.

Here is an algorithm that should solve it.

```
1. If the graph can be a forest and not a tree
       create a new node root
       Make all roots in forest point to this root as parent
2. For every node, create an array (stack) of its children, call it c[i].
3. For each vertex v in tree
       c[v.parent].push(v)
4. u = root, i = 0
5. print u
6. while c[root] is not empty and u != root
       if c[u] is not empty
           u = pop(c[u])
           i++
           print tab i times
           print u
       if c[u] is empty and u != root
           u = u.parent
           i--
```